# Ruby on Rails redirect_to method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, erb

Let's say I have this line in my controller

```
redirect_to "/sessions/try", provider: 5
```

and this is my `try.html.erb`

```
<h1>try</h1>
<%= provider %>
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but how would I get 'provider' to show up in my html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send provider as params

```
redirect_to "/sessions/try?provider=5"
```

Than at, try.html.erb

```
<h1>try</h1>
<%= params[:provider] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a named route for `/sessions/try`, then you'll have to hardcode the params into the string that you pass to `redirect_to`:

```
redirect_to "/sessions/try?provider=5"
```

or

```
hash = { provider: 5 }
redirect_to "/sessions/try?#{hash.to_param}"
```

But if you have named route like `try_sessions_path`, then you can use:

```
redirect_to try_sessions_path(provider: 5)
```

In your view, you will then get the keys in `params` hash:

```
<%= params[:provider] %>
```